# Showing Angle Measurement of an image

Tags: java, android, rotation, label, degrees

I have an image on my view. I am rotating the image like this:

```
image4.setRotation(image4.getRotation() - 1);
```

The next thing I need, is to show the angle measurement of the rotation of the image... So the label will show "45 degrees" or whatever the angle measurement is.

Comment: If my answer worked, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Set the label to show image4.getRotation(); According to the Developers site it returns a float of the degrees around the pivot point.

float   getRotation()
The degrees that the view is rotated around the pivot point.

You could also call
getRotationX()
The degrees that the view is rotated around the horizontal axis through the pivot point.

Or

getRotationY()
The degrees that the view is rotated around the vertical axis through the pivot point.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: how should i make the label show image4.getRotation(); ?

Comment: yourLabel.setText(Float.toString(image4.getRotation())); assuming yourLabel is a TextView

Comment: I have put that code right under the rotation code, and their is no errors. But when i put the 'float getRotation()' under that code, i get some errors..  getRotation turns grey and '()' has a red line under it.   Why is that? How can i fix that?

Comment: my code looks like this   text1.setText(Float.toString(red.getRotation()));
                float getRotationX()

Comment: Delete everything after the semicolon

Comment: @sweatshirt If it worked please accept the answer. If it didn't work let me know what didn't work.